# generate text field on button click in swift

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

there r `2 buttons` in a view. If I click `button 1` then

```
text field 1 appear
text field 2 appear
```

If I click button 2 then

```
text field 3 appear
text field 4 appear
```

[image: view with button]  [image: view 2 with text field]

all text field will come in a single view and all button in another view.
Is it possible to do in swift. Not getting how to do.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you necessarily need to generate them programmatically? Or you can also do this with the storyboard and hide them?

Comment: use NSNotification Center or Delegates for your concept

Comment: Please Answer Our Questions!

Comment: @Xcoder123 doing it programatically would be good

Comment: OK. I am thinking about it!

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik ok, I'm checking this.

Comment: @ripa - choice is your create progrmatiically or already added in strory board , use  NSNotification Center or Delegates based on touch visible the textfield with condition

Comment: You can create a UIView and add textFields on them. On your button click just add this view as a subview .

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like on button's click,

```
 let myTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(20, 100, 300, 40))  //your desired frame here
    myTextField.placeholder = "Placeholder here"
    self.view.addSubview(myTextField)  // here your view on which you want to add textfield
```

Comment: actually problem is button and view will not appear in same view. they r in different view.

Comment: view or viewcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing them in different views, then use a segue and pass a variable which will identify which textfields to show. Use two different segues and assign each segue to each button:

First View:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue == "button1" {
            let secondVC = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
            secondVC.textfields = [1,2]
        } else {
            secondVC.textFields = [3,4]
        }    

}
```

And then in the SecondViewController, hide the textfields that are not to be shown. In viewDidLoad, remember to hide all of the textfields initially (or in Storyboard) and then change `.hidden` to false for the corresponding textFields.